# How to extract text that is inside quotes with regex or preg_match?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I receive as text the following string:

`We have a new FB Leads "Puente Middleware".`

The theme that I tried to extract the string with preg_match but it only returns the text that is outside the quotes and not inside.

```
$getSubject = preg_match('/"([^"]*)"/', $subject);
return "We have a new FB Leads"

I want to return "Puente Middleware"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a correct capture group, but you never accessed the replacement.  Try this version:

```php
$subject = "We have a new FB Leads \"Puente Middleware\"";
preg_match('/"([^"]*)"/', $subject, $results);
echo $results[1];
```

This prints:

```
Puente Middleware
```